# How to close a single excel file, not all excel files which are currently opened using java

Tags: java, excel

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(75, 124, 1095, 480);
    File file = new File("screen-capture.jpg");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\AnubhavPatel\\Desktop\\Testing_Code.xlsx"));
    Thread.sleep(7000);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    boolean status = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", file);
    System.out.println("Screen Captured ? " + status + " File Path:- " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /f /im excel.exe");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file with a library, and then close it with the library's close command.

Right now, you are sending a kill command to Excel.  Excel doesn't get a message you want to close a file, it gets the message it needs to shut down.  You can't make this kind of an approach inform excel to close a file.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach-

```
//Open the excel file using Desktop.getDesktop()
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new 
File("C:\\Users\\AnubhavPatel\\Desktop\\Testing_Code_Macro.xlsm"));
Thread.sleep(5000);
//Save and close it using robot class
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

Thread.sleep(5000);

//Then write to it using outputStream   
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
        "C://Users//AnubhavPatel//Desktop/Testing_Code_Macro.xlsm");
workbook.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```